# How can this CNN have an odd number of parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am planning to work with a 3-D U-Net, and for first steps I am following the paper by Çiçek et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06650, from which I reproduce the network structure here:
[image]

They reportedly use a number 19,069,955 parameters. This number is odd (by which I mean, not divisible by 2). My own Keras implementations get quite close to that number (e.g., 19,067,648 parameters when using 2 instead of 3 input channels, or 19,068,448 when using 2 instead of 3 target classes). But whatever I try, my numbers of (trainable, non-trainable, total - in each layer) parameters remains even. How can this network have an odd number of parameters?

Comment: Probably some parameter between layers, such as batch normalization parameters. One of these in-between layer pieces probably just isn't included at either the start or the end.

Comment: @golmschenk I was thinking the same, but a Keras BN layer has 4 (either 2+2 or 0+4, trainable+non-trainable) parameters.

Comment: First, my implicit assumption that a layer with even depth in its input or its output cannot have an odd number of parameters is incorrect; I guess it's true only for layers with an even depth in their outputs, but not so for layers with even input depths (if they have an odd output depth). In fact, without any batch normalization, the final 1x1 conv layer has an odd number of parameters, namely, `195 = 3*(1*1*64 + 1)`. I forgot to account for the biases (as always) by adding `+1`.

Comment: Second, I had been getting only even number as I was using `use_bias=False` in the Conv layers before batch normalization: computing activations *after* batch normalization, my thinking was that these biases would not be required. Well, maybe they are, maybe not, but Cicek et all did not disable them apparently.